# How to display user input which was taken in another intent in Dialogflow?

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

usually, we use '$' to access the values. eg: Age is $age. but this only works if "age" is inputted in the current intent. What if I have a series of intents connected using contexts (followup intents) and at last I want to display all the input values to the user.

Answer (score 2):

You can access this name in Dialogflow by entering **#context_name.parameter_name** (where context_name is the name of the context and parameter_name is the name of the parameter). This works for any response, as long as the context is currently active and the user has provided a value for the parameter.